# "No such file or directory" on simple bash redirection

Tags: bash, io-redirection

Here is some code of mine:

```
gzip -c $path > /var/www/wiki/backup/$now/$file.gz
```

I'm gzipping the contents of `$path` (the path to a directory), and then sending the compressed file to `/var/www/wiki/backup/$now/$file.gz`. `$now` contains a directory name, `$file` is the name I want to write the compressed file to.

However, on running the program, I get this error:

```
backup.sh: line 20: /var/www/wiki/backup/Sunday/extensions.gz: No such file or directory
                                         ^$now    ^$file
```

(line 20 is the line given above)

Why is the program breaking? I know `Sunday/extensions.gz` doesn't exist (although Sunday does), that's why I'm asking you to write to it!

Full program code:

```
#!/bin/bash

now=$(date +"%A")
mkdir -p /var/www/wiki/backups/$now

databases=(bmshared brickimedia_meta brickimedia_en brickimedia_customs)
locations=("/var/www/wiki/skins" "/var/www/wiki/images" "/var/www/wiki/")

for db in ${databases[*]}
do
#command with passwords and shoodle
:
done

for path in ${locations[*]}
do
#echo "" > var/www/wiki/backup/$now/$file.gz
file=`echo $path | cut -d/ -f5`
echo $path
gzip -c $path > /var/www/wiki/backup/$now/$file.gz
done
```

Comment: Does the path /var/..../Sunday exist?

Comment: @suspectus Yes. (I created it at the top of the file!) (Should this matter?)

Comment: my speed reading is not appropriate sometimes!

Comment: Can you post more of the script? That error really only makes sense if `/var/www/wiki/backup/Sunday/` does not exist when `gzip` executes.

Comment: Presumably the gzip is run daily - but perhaps not on a Sunday?

Comment: @suspectus well I intend to run this script daily, if that's what you mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The directory created is **backups**, the gzip is to **backup**.

```
mkdir -p /var/www/wiki/backups/$now

gzip -c $path > /var/www/wiki/backup/$now/$file.gz
```

Comment: This answer actually helped me... turns out I typo'ed too!

Answer (score 1):

One of your locations is "/var/www/wiki/".  Then you have

```
file=`echo $path | cut -d/ -f5`
gzip -c $path > /var/www/wiki/backup/$now/$file.gz
```

Since `$file` contains the empty string, you're attempting to write to `/var/www/wiki/backup/Sunday/.gz`. That's a problem but it's not the error you're reporting.

When I try to gzip a directory, I get this error

```
$ gzip -c ./subdir/ > subdir.gz
gzip: ./subdir/ is a directory -- ignored
```

That's a problem but it's not the error you're reporting.

@suspectus solved your reported problem.